# dotnet test case does not obey solution build order

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a YAML pipeline which doesnt always obey the project build order

```
 - job: Job_1
    displayName: Agent job 1
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-2019
    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: '.NET Core 3.1.404'
      inputs:
        version: '3.1.404'
        packageType: sdk
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      enabled: true
      displayName: dotnet test
      continueOnError: falsefo
      inputs:
        command: test
        projects: '**/*test/*.csproj'
        arguments: --configuration $(buildConfiguration) 
        publishTestResults: true
```

This means that for some executions of the pipeline I get the error

Unable to find package NETStandard.Library with version (>= 2.0.3)

This occurs on a project that is not first to build in Visual Studio

Is there anyway of enforcing the build order?  Or getting this package?

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to find package NETStandard.Library with version (>= 2.0.3). Is
> there anyway of enforcing the build order? Or getting this package?

The problem is that the NETStandard.Library package was not found. I think it has nothing to do with the build order of the projects. NETStandard.Library is a nuget package, you can try to add a [nuget restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops#restore) task to the pipeline.

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
```

Comment: Ok thanks I can try this but the strange thing is that the pipeline works most of the time just fails with this issue occasionally

Comment: I dont have a nuget.config file and when I search for this there are several files none of them are in the solution folder?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway of enforcing the build order? Or getting this package?

You could build/test the specify project at first:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  enabled: true
  displayName: dotnet test
  continueOnError: falsefo
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*test/TheSpecifyProject.csproj'
    arguments: --configuration $(buildConfiguration) 
    publishTestResults: true
```

Then build/test other projects:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  enabled: true
  displayName: dotnet test
  continueOnError: falsefo
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*test/*.csproj'
    arguments: --configuration $(buildConfiguration) 
    publishTestResults: true
```

Or

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  enabled: true
  displayName: dotnet test
  continueOnError: falsefo
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: |
     **/*test/*.csproj
     !**/*test/TheSpecifyProject.csproj
    arguments: --configuration $(buildConfiguration) 
    publishTestResults: true
```